# js ajax code doesn't work normally. first one is not displaying in the connected two xhr functions

Tags: javascript, ajax

fiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/xvwz2bt4/

I'm using below ajax code (pure js) :

```
var xhr;
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
function xhrDocOpen(doc,placeID){
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
            document.getElementById(placeID).innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET',doc,true);
    xhr.send();
}
xhrDocOpen('a.txt','apple');
xhrDocOpen('b.txt','banana');
```

First time, I thought this code is fine.

But later, I found it's not functioning normally.

In above 'xhrDocOpen' function, first one is not displaying a.txt... But second one displays b.txt normally.

I don't know why...

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to test this on my local machine and it looks like you are using the same `XMLHttpRequest` for each call to `xhrDocOpen` and doing so in quick succession will cause the `onreadystatechange` function to be set to the last one set in the last call to `xhrDocOpen` before the first call finishes. So a.text will never get set.  If you move the `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` into the `xhrDocOpen` function it should work.